# Next without for error

Tags: excel, vba

I tried doing 'Next cell' but no dice. I'm trying to go down the column starting at G2 and dump the results in a different worksheet.

```
For Each cell In Range("G2").End(xlDown)
    If cell.Value = "New York" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
    ReDim partnerArray(0 To i)
        partnerArray(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

 Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ("By Resource Level")
    Range("A1").Value = partnerArray
```

Comment: The code displayed here has an IF statement inside a FOR loop, but the IF statement does not have an End If.  If this isn't the real code then please fix the example.  Also is it possible to edit this question into an actual question?

Answer (score 1):

End(xlDown) goes to the last cell in a range, as if you are clicking `ctrl down` so you are only ever picking up one value in your code.

With regards to partnerArray giving a mismatch error, this is because you are trying to put an array of data into one cell rather than specifying a subscript i.e `partnerArray(0)`

If you want all results, you will need to loop through the array and enter each result to a different cell. I'll show you an example of the code shortly

EDIT:

```
For Each cell In Range("G2:G10").Cells
    If cell.Value = "New York" Then
        ReDim Preserve partnerArray(i)
        cell.Select
        partnerArray(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next

On Error Resume Next

For i = LBound(partnerArray) To UBound(partnerArray)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("By Resource Level").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = partnerArray(i)
Next i
```

Comment: @STANGMMX, Steven's answer is much more complete than mine (I was just trying to answer your initial question). Go with this and please let us know how it works.

Comment: Apologies, I went beyond the question a bit there but hopefully this will resolve any other issues you were having. Thanks for the edit PU

Comment: Actually this doesn't print to the newly created worksheet for some reaosn.

Comment: No? I tested it and it works for me. Maybe take out the error handler and see if anything is happening

Comment: Just to confirm - this code is picking up the data from the active sheet in column E, based on column G and returning it to the "By Resource Level" sheet

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sometimes displays error messages that aren't the real source of the error.  In this case, you didn't close your If statement:

```
For Each cell In Range("G2").End(xlDown)
    If cell.Value = "New York" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
        ReDim partnerArray(0 To i)
        partnerArray(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
    Endif

 Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ("By Resource Level")
    Range("A1").Value = partnerArray
```

Comment: Ah. Makes sense. Any idea why i'd get a mismatch error at Range("A1").Value = partnerArray??

Comment: Also, if you remove the () at the Dim, you get a out of memory error.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `End If` before your `Next`